# C++ copy elision with ctor calls

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I am trying to figure out how to better organize my code, so I've made a simple example representing the issue:

Given ClassA and ClassB:

```
class ClassA
{
public:

    ClassA() { cout << "ClassA ctor\n"; }

    ClassA(const ClassA &other) { cout << "ClassA copy ctor\n"; }

    ClassA& operator=(ClassA other) {
        cout << "ClassA assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~ClassA() { cout << "ClassA destructor\n"; }
};

class ClassB {
    ClassA mA;
public:

    ClassB(ClassA a) : mA(a) {
        cout << "ClassB ctor\n";
    }

    ~ClassB() { cout << "ClassB destructor\n"; }
};
```

Can somebody explain if there is a way why this code works:

```
void test3(ClassA pA) { cout << "Test3\n"; }
...
test3(ClassA());
```

producing the output:

> ClassA ctor
>
> Test3
>
> ClassA destructor

While this code doesn't:

```
ClassB b(ClassA());
```

ClassB constructor is not even being executed in this case (although no error is thrown either).

Is there a way to avoid copy ctor when passing argument by value to a ctor?

Comment: `ClassB` constructor takes a non-const reference as a parameter. `ClassA()` is a temporary. A temporary cannot bind to non-const reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `ClassB` takes an instance of  `ClassA` by value not by reference.

Comment: @CaptainObvious Well, it does now. It didn't a minute ago.

Comment: @Igor sorry I've made mistake in post, it is by value in code.

Comment: In `ClassB(ClassA());`, if it weren't for copy elision, you'd see a copy constructor called *twice*: once to copy `ClassA()` temporary to function parameter, and again to copy this parameter to `mA` member variable. The first copy is elided, the same way it is in `test3` call. But there ain't no way to elide the second copy, the `mA(a)` part.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no it doesnt even call B's constructor (no output printed in console). If I change it to 'ClassA a; ClassB b(a);' then it works, with copy ctor being called once.

Comment: Ah. Most vexing parse. `ClassB b(ClassA());` declares a function named `b` returning `ClassB` and taking a parameter of type "function with no parameters returning `ClassA`" - not an object of type `ClassB`. As there's no object, there's nothing to construct.

Comment: There is no copy elision happening, it's just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse As for: _"Is there a way to avoid copy ctor when passing argument by value to a ctor?"_ -- there is no copy constructor call, what are you talking about?! It's already elided! You can't make it do as little as `ClassB b(ClassA());` because that does **nothing** but that's probably not what you want.